# Floating point conditionals in Gforth

Tags: conditional-statements, forth, gforth

Using integers, you can simply make conditional statements like so:

```
5 4 > . // -1
4 5 > . // 0

variable foo //ok
6 foo ! //ok
foo @ 5 > . // -1
```

Now is there a simple way to do this with floating point numbers? I have tried this:

```
4.2 5.4 > . //-1 - Wrong
4.2e 5.4e > . //-1 - Wrong
4.2e 5.4e f> f. //error
```

Is it possible to do?

EDIT:

To expand this, how can i do this with variables

```
 fvariable foo 6.2 foo f!
 fvariable boo 8.2 boo f!

 boo @ foo @ f> //How is this done?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`4.5` in Forth is not a floating point number, but a double integer.  You correctly found the `e` syntax for floats and `f>` for comparing them.  However, the result from `f>` is a normal integer.

```
4.2e 5.4e f> .
```